# How do I format my MySql table to avoid a "Incorrect string value" error?

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-3.x, docker

I'm using Python 3.7, Django 2.0 and Mysql 5.7, all set up through docker containers.  I'm trying to insert the following seed data into one of my tables ...

```
- model: address.state
  pk: 14970
  fields:
    name: "Xocal\u0131"
    code: XCI
    country: 266
```

This results in the MySql error, "Could not load address.State(pk=14750): (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\xC4\x81n' for column 'name' at row 1")"

```
web_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 209, in execute
web_1     |     res = self._query(query)
web_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 315, in _query
web_1     |     db.query(q)
web_1     |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 239, in query
web_1     |     _mysql.connection.query(self, query)
web_1     | django.db.utils.OperationalError: Problem installing fixture '/app/maps/fixtures/state_data.yaml': Could not load address.State(pk=14750): (1366, "Incorrect string value: '\\xC4\\x81n' for column 'name' at row 1")
```

Below is my table description ...

```
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| address_state | CREATE TABLE `address_state` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(165) NOT NULL,
  `code` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
  `country_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `address_state_name_country_id_a46a5987_uniq` (`name`,`country_id`),
  KEY `address_state_country_id_0a4efd43_fk_address_country_id` (`country_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `address_state_country_id_0a4efd43_fk_address_country_id` FOREIGN KEY (`country_id`) REFERENCES `address_country` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
+---------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

What can I do to format my table so that I can insert my value properly?  The table was automatically generated through a migration based on the Django address module -- https://github.com/furious-luke/django-address

Answer (score 0):

`CHARSET=latin1` is the important bit.

You could change the table character set:

```
ALTER TABLE address_state CHARSET=utf8mb4
```

Comment: Thanks.  In as far as these tables seem to get generated from my Django migrations, you wouldn't happen to know what I need to do to change the character set in there, would you?